# What are possible methods of interfacing with a button on a PCB?

Tags: button

I have bought an electrical appliance which has buttons sticking out of it. I want to interface with these buttons from a microcontroller, but the buttons are baked on a flex PCB in the underlying circuitry. I can not get to their pins, partly because I'll void warranty, and therefore I decided that a mechanical solution would be best. I would've much preferred an optoisolator wired to the signal lines, but it showed that it can't be done.

I measured the force needed to press the button and calculated that it would be around **4 Newton**. (Placed object on scale, zeroed and measured weight while pressing button)

Because the electrical appliance is quite small (approx. 60x60x60mm) and my power supply is limited to **5V 2A** I started looking at **linear solenoid**s within this range and found that they are unable to deliver the required force. I then thought of using a **stepper motor with gearbox**, but this feels a bit overkill.

What are some recommendations to interface with either the physical button or its underlying circuitry, keeping in mind the constraints?

Comment: "I can not get to their pins and therefore I decided that a mechanical solution would be best." I question your decision here. It should be possible to interface to the buttons, they might be on a flexible PCB but they also need to interface to something that is (much likely) soldered to a standard PCB. Can you post some pictures of your device?

Comment: I would love to but another reason for not wanting to open it, which I should make more clear in the question, is that I will void warranty

Comment: "which I should make more clear in the question" - You can still edit your question and fix that.

Comment: @Dampmaskin I know but I was stuffing a sandwich in my face! Will correct it shortly.

Comment: I think that externally (mechanically) interfacing to those buttons will be unreliable as hell. In some cases you'll end up in missed hits, especially on the appliance side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the button travel is not too much, you should be able to find a hobby servo that can generate that much force at the end of a short arm within your power requirements. This has the added advantage of being very cheap and easy.

https://www.pololu.com/blog/16/electrical-characteristics-of-servos-and-introduction-to-the-servo-control-interface

If a hobby servo will not work for this because of geometry constraints, then a photo of the buttons configuration might get better answers.

Comment: Tried it out using one I found at home on a scale and 4N was reached easily. Without any reduction/leverage the circular motion is something to consider in my final design